# What version of Dialogflow CX has the class AgentsClient

Tags: dialogflow-cx

The online tutorial for using the Java SDK to interact with Dialogflow CX has the following line of code

```
AgentsSettings agentsSettings = AgentsSettings.newBuilder().setEndpoint(apiEndpoint).build();
AgentsClient client = AgentsClient.create(agentsSettings);
```

However I cannot find any install for the DF CX SDK containing those classes?  They show up in the online Javadoc.  ??

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question and 1.) add the full stacktrace of the error 2.) what version of Dialogflow CX are you using?

Comment: I don't get as far as stacktrace.  The problem is in the IDE (Intellij) cannot locate the classes.  Here is my build.gradle snippet.

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:24.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google:google-cloud-dialogflow-cx-v3'
}